# CG spaces from the perspective of sheaves over compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, compactness, condensed-mathematics

A compactly generated space is a space $X$ such that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $K \rightarrow X \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} Y$ is continuous for each compact hausdorff space $K$.

Let $I$ be the category of compact hausdorff topological spaces with continuous maps. I think being compactly generated is equivalent to the canonical map $\epsilon_X : \int_{K \in I} [K, X]_{\text{Top}} \times K \rightarrow X$ being an isomorphism. $\epsilon_X$ is the counit of an adjunction between functors $L : [ I^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}} \rightarrow \text{Top}$ sending $S$ to $\int_{K \in I} S(K) \times K$ and $R : \text{Top} \rightarrow [ I^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$ sending a space $X$ to the presheaf $S : I^{op} \rightarrow \text{Set}$ sending $K$ to $[K, X ]_{\text{Top}}$. $L$ is the left Kan extension of the inclusion $\iota : I \rightarrow \text{Top}$ along the yoneda embedding $Y : I \rightarrow [I^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$, as in the diagram below:
[image]

That $L$ is left adjoint to $R$ is a famous theorem, which was discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252383/the-kan-construction-profunctors-and-kan-extensions).

If I am not mistaken, this adjunction is related to Peter Scholze and Dustin Clausen's condensed mathematics. Surprisingly, there is no information lost if we take instead of $I$ the smaller category of profinite sets. There is a fully faithful functor from compactly generated spaces to condensed sets (sheaves on the étale site of a point) that arises in this way.

My question is, has anyone taken this perspective to get a streamlined, categorical proof that the category of compactly generated spaces is cartesian closed? We might start by observing that the category of presheaves on $I$ has all small limits and colimits, $L$ preserves colimits, and $R$ preserves limits. Might this allow us to carry over the cartesian closed-ness of $[I^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$ to the category of compactly generated spaces?

Comment: How do you prove that (compactly generated) is equivalent to ($\epsilon_X$ iso)?

Comment: More or less by definition, $X$ is compactly generated (in your sense; I would say "k-space") if and only if $\epsilon_X$ is a quotient map.  But why must $X$ being a k-space imply that $\epsilon_X$ is also a bijection?

Comment: If in addition $X$ is assumed to be weak Hausdorff (or more generally, if the diagonal is k-closed in $X\times X$), then I think it is true that $X$ is a k-space iff $\epsilon_X$ is iso, basically because for any pair of maps $K_i\to X$ from cptHaus spaces the fiber product $K_1\times_X K_2$ is also cptHaus.

Comment: @CharlesRezk I think he is actually right.  His definition of compactly generated sounds to me like "$X$ is the colimits of the canonical diagram induced by $I$", this is equivalent to say that the codensity monad of I in Top fixes $X$, which leads to $\epsilon_X$ is an isomorphism. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti OK, I see it now.

Comment: @DeanYoung you might want to give a look to A4.3.1 in Sketches of an Elephant, where inheritance of cc by reflective subcategories is characterized.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti thanks so much!

Comment: (Just to clarify, in my comment directed to prof. Rezk I meant density comonad. Sorry).

Comment: W.r.t your last comment- Indeed, this adjunction seems like it is an idempotent adjunction, so that it factors as a categorical equivalence, a reflexive adjunction, and a coreflexive embedding.

Comment: "Topologists don't want to know about it!"

Comment: @DavidRoberts that's amusing, can you explain?

Comment: Your question title sounds like the sort of clickbaity titles you see in websites that contain poorly-written articles pushing some new fad ("Lose belly fat with this trick. Doctors don't want you know about it!" type of thing). It's the phrase "...this adjunction" that triggers the association. I mean, you could have specified the adjunction, but leaving it mysterious makes people click through and read the body. A lot of this stuff was developed by algorithms IIRC, so the word "weird" is often also used (imagine if you'd used "...from the perspective of this weird adjunction" :-P)

Comment: @DavidRoberts that's funny. I think I'll change the title now, ha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following paper seems worth looking at, although I am not certain whether the proofs therein are related to yours:

> Martín Escardó, Jimmie Lawson, Alex Simpson: *Comparing Cartesian closed categories of (core) compactly generated spaces*. Topology and its Applications
>   Volume 143, Issues 1–3, 28 August 2004, Pages 105-145.

The [evil link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2004.02.011) and the [good link](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/ELS03.pdf) are both available.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read this and see if it sheds any light here.

Comment: Thanks for including both links!

Comment: Perhaps we could adopt more precise language than "evil" and "good." I suggest "private" and "published," respectively.

Comment: I used "evil" and "good" for a reason and they are precisely the words that express my attitude.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer using Ivan Di Liberti's very helpful reference in the comments. I figured I would post it here in case anyone has interest in this approach to compactly generated spaces in the future.

For a cardinal $\kappa$, let $I_{\kappa}$ be the category of compact hausdorff spaces with cardinality less than or equal to $\kappa$. The cardinal is to deal with size issues. We make $I_{\kappa}$ into a site where covers are jointly surjective collections of maps. $I_{\kappa}$ induces an adjunction between $\text{Sh}( I_{\kappa}^{op})$, the category of sheaves of sets on $I_{\kappa}^{op}$, and $\text{Top}$. The left adjoint $L$ sends $F$ to $\int_{K \in I_{\kappa}} F(K) \times K$, and the right adjoint $R$ sends $X$ to the sheaf sending $K$ to $[K, X]_{\text{Top}}$. $L$ is a left Kan extension of $I_{\kappa} \rightarrow \text{Top}$ along the inclusion $I_{\kappa} \rightarrow \text{Sh}( I_{\kappa}^{op})$.

This adjunction between $L$ and $R$ is [idempotent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+adjunction); it factors as $\text{Sh}( I_{\kappa}^{op}) \leftrightarrow \text{CG}_{\kappa} \leftrightarrow \text{Top}$, where $\text{CG}$ is what I call $\kappa$-compactly generated spaces. $\text{CG}_{\kappa}$ is a reflexive subcategory of $\text{Sh}( I_{\kappa}^{op})$ and a coreflexive subcategory of $\text{Top}$. What Ivan Di Liberti realized is that this may allow us to apply proposition 4.3.1 in The Elephant. Let $L' : \text{Sh}( I_{\kappa}^{op}) \leftrightarrow \text{CG}  : R'$ be the reflexive adjunction. To show that $\text{CG}_{\kappa}$ inherits a cartesian closed structure from $\text{Sh}(I_{\kappa}^{op})$, it suffices to show that $L'$ preserves products.

$L'$ sends a representable sheaf $[-, K]$ to $K$. It preserves products of compact hausdorff spaces; the canonical map $L'([-, K] \times [-, K']) \rightarrow L'([-, K]) \times L'([-, K'])$ is an isomorphism. To see this, note that it is a bijection (one can show that it is an isomorphism after composing with the forgetful functor to set, and this can be made very canonical). Now the famous lemma about a continuous map from a compact space to a hausdorff space being open finishes the job.

This result can be extended to work for the general case. $\text{Sh}(I^{op}_{\kappa})$ is a sheaf topos. It is therefore locally presentable (see Borceux, *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*, prop. 3.4.16, page 220). So there is a small set of $\lambda$-small objects which generates this category under $\lambda$-filtered colimits. Every sheaf is a $\lambda$-filtered colimit of representables here. $L'$ and products commute with $\lambda$-filtered colimits, reducing to the previous paragraph.

Now it seems that, if we take the large colimits $\text{colimit } \text{Sh}(I_{\kappa}^{op})$ and $\text{colimit }  \text{CG}_{\kappa}$, I think we obtain compactly generated spaces, along with the desired product preserving reflexive adjunction.