# Left Kan extension that preserves colimit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'd be very happy if the question [When do Kan extensions preserve limits/colimits?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112137/when-do-kan-extensions-preserve-limits-colimits) has been fully answered. But it seems not.

I have a more specific question though. Let $C$ be a site (essentially small to be safe) equipped with some subcanonical Grothendieck topology, $PSh$ be its category of presheaves. Then it's well-known that for any functor $C \to B$ with $B$ cocomplete, the left Kan extension $PSh \to B$ along the Yoneda embedding $C \to PSh$ necessarily  preserves colimit. Is it true if I replace $PSh$ by the category of sheaves $Sh$? In other words, does the left Kan extension along $C \xrightarrow{Yoneda} PSh \xrightarrow{sheafification} Sh$ preserve colimit? If in general not, is there any sufficient condition we can impose on the functor $C \to B$?

Answer (score 6):

Usually it does not. We can take $C \to B$ to be the universal example of a functor to a cocomplete category, namely the Yoneda embedding $C \to PSh$. Then the left Kan extension of $y : C \to PSh$ along $j : C \to PSh \to Sh$ is the inclusion $Sh \to PSh$, and this usually does not preserve colimits. The calculation of this left Kan extension can be verified using the coend formula:
$$
(Lan_j y)(X) = \int^{c : C} Sh(jc, X) \otimes yc
= \int^{c : C} X(c) \otimes yc = X
$$
where the second equality used the fact that the topology is subcanonical.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample! Is there any sufficient condition on the functor $C \to B$ that can guarantee the left Kan extension is colimit preserving?

Comment: E.g. if $F:C \to B$ is a subfunctor of a functor $F':C \to B$ whose left Kan extension is colimit preserving, is the left kan extension of $F$ colimit preserving?